# Customizing Text in the Content Type H1 Tag

Tags: plone

The H1 tag (for Title field) output of a view for the Dexterity type, typically looks like:

> <h1 id="parent-fieldname-title" class="documentFirstHeading">
>   My Title
>   </h1>

I want to add some customized tag for the text in H1 tag, says:

> <h1 id="parent-fieldname-title" class="documentFirstHeading">
>   <span style="text-decoration: line-through;">My</span> Title
>   </h1>

This will make `My` a strikethrough text. As already known, if I add `<span ...>` in the title field, they are literally displayed. Is there an easy way for such customization?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Title field is a plain-text field, so any text is escaped when the page renders. This is by design.

If you explicitly want to allow HTML to be entered, you'll need to customize the title display for your type and add `structure` to the `<h1>` element:

```
<h1 tal:content="structure context/title">Title</h1>
```

The `structure` TALES keyword disables HTML escaping. *This allows the editor to insert arbitrary HTML*.

You may want to switch to using a `RichText` field instead of the default `TextLine`, so you can apply the automatic safe-HTML transformations on it. See the [Rich text, markup and transformations chapter](http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/advanced/rich-text-markup-and-transformations) in the Dexterity developer manual.